# How to Configure/Install HotSpotShield?

Tags: installation, software-recommendation

How to Configure/Install [HotSpotShield](http://hotspotshield.com/) under Ubuntu 11.04;

Are there any other OpenSource VPN <strike>thru which we can see sites like
 [www.hulu.com](http://www.hulu.com) which are restricted outside of USA especially thru ubuntu 11.04+</strike>.

> > Let me put this way, I wanted surf web securely by having dedicated secure VPN and I want keep the server at a centralized place. I usually travel in and out of USA; Currently I would like to try out home grown solution or open source service.

Refer (The below sites says about installation and configuration)

1. http://www.kalvster.com/tools/vpn-ubuntu-hotspot-shield.html
2. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Njp--ZOEUfA

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you will find many good free proxies/VPN servers that aren't blocked by Hulu. You may want to consider a paid VPN service. HotSpotShield is also not the best choice espessialy on a non-Windows computer.
You should also consider that you are violating the Hulu TOS.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are alternatives like [Open VPN](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/openvpn), [Freenet](http://freenetproject.org/), and [others](http://alternativeto.net/software/hotspot-shield/).